# SQL Data Conversion

Tags: sql

Any ideas why this won't work?

```
 Select [Name]
      ,TimeStamp
      ,UserKey
      ,Field
      ,WasValue
      ,Cast(IsValue as int)
    From DebtorHistory
    Left Join Debtors on Debtors.DebtorKey = DebtorHistory.DebtorKey
    Where Field = 'Total Credit Limit'
    and TimeStamp > GETDATE()-7
```

I'm getting this error when trying to convert isValue to int:

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '15,000.00' to data type int.

Comment: tag your dbms please

Comment: post both tables structure with datatypes

Answer (score 0):

you have thousand separator "," in your string (IsValue) which can;t be converted into int, you can remove it by `replace`:

```
Select [Name]
      ,TimeStamp
      ,UserKey
      ,Field
      ,WasValue
      ,Cast(replace(IsValue,',','') as int)  -- <-- replace , with empty string
    From DebtorHistory
    Left Join Debtors on Debtors.DebtorKey = DebtorHistory.DebtorKey
    Where Field = 'Total Credit Limit'
    and TimeStamp > GETDATE()-7
```

Answer (score 0):

The `money` format understands comma separators.  So you can use:

```
select cast(cast('15,000.00' as money) as int)
```

That is:

```
select cast(cast(IsValue as money) as int)
```